# how do you model your javascript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, documentation

I'm trying to model my javascript object using visio, visio doesn't support javascript data types. 
Then I start thinking, how do you desing model your javascript code?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I've used Open Source tools like Dia and just fudged the data types where needed...

It's enough to get the idea across, but you're definitely not going to get anything even close to code generation from it.

Comment: thanks, I'n not looking for code generation, just design & document

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Object Oriented design - even for JavaScript - so I suggest Rational Rose.  I like some of the features of OO (e.g. encapsulation and abstraction) and like to add some discipline to a potentially undisciplined environment - especially when working with developers new to JavaScript.  Rose meets my needs.